# Irreducibility of graph homomorphism polynomial $hom(F,H)$ when $F$ is a simple and connected graph

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, graph-theory

Let $F$  and $G$ be simple graphs. Let $hom(F,G)$ be the number of graph homomorphisms  $\psi:F \to G$.  Let $H$ be a symmetric and weighed graph on [n] nodes in which the nodeweights are 1, and the edge weights are different variables $x_ {ij}$. Hence $H$ contains $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ variables.  Thena
$$
hom(F,H) = \sum_{\psi: V(F) \to [n]} \prod_{ij \in E(F)} x_{\psi(i) \psi(j)}
$$
Clearly $hom(F,H) $ is polynomial on  $x_{ij}$.

It is not difficult to check that if $F=F_1 \sqcup F_2$ is the disjoint union of graphs $F_1$ and $F_2$ then $hom(F_1 \sqcup F_2, H) = hom(F_1, H) hom(F_2, H)$.

My question is if $F$ is a connected graph $hom(F, H)$ is necessarily an irreducible polynomial. That means that there are no polynomials $P(H)$ and $Q(H)$ such that $hom(F, H) = P(H) Q(H)$?.

Do you know if someone has investigated this question?

Comment: This sounds like Edge ideals. Have you checked the literature on this topic? Can you clarify where is $H$ in the RHS of the main equation?

Comment: @Phicar thanks for the info I didn't know about Edge Ideals,. $H$ can be seen as a symmetric matrix whose entries in the upper triangle are $x_{ij}$ .